# download all column into excel sheet

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a table **mainaccount**, in which 20 column exists, but showing only two column **Email** and **mobile**. Now I want to download all column into excel sheet. I have a code. But it is not working . Can anyone help please?

**Error are : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\wamp\www\export_to_excel\export_to_excel\index.php on line 83**

```
    <?php
    include("connection.php");

   $data1 = mysql_query("select * from mainaccount order by id DESC") or die(mysql_error());

                        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($data1)){

                        ?>

                        <?

      if(isset($_POST["ExportType"]))
    {

    switch($_POST["ExportType"])
    {
    case "export-to-excel" :
        // Submission from
        $filename = $_POST["ExportType"] . ".xls";       
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        ExportFile($data);
        //$_POST["ExportType"] = '';
        exit();
    default :
        die("Unknown action : ".$_POST["action"]);
        break;
    }
    }
    function ExportFile($records) {
     $heading = false;
    if(!empty($records))
      foreach($records as $row) {
        if(!$heading) {
          // display field/column names as a first row
          echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
          $heading = true;
        }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
      }
    exit;
     }

   ?>

   <?php } ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <div> 
     <div id="container" >
      <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
              <div class="well well-sm col-sm-12">
                  <b id='project-capacity-count-lable'><?php echo count($data);?></b> records found.
               <div class="btn-group pull-right">

        <ul class="" role="menu" id="export-menu">
       <li id="export-to-excel"><a href="#">Export to excel</a></li>

       </ul>
      </div>

                  </div>
                  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="export-form">
                    <input type="hidden" value='' id='hidden-type' name='ExportType'/>
                  </form>
               <table id="" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>

              </tr>

            <?php   $res5 = mysql_query("select * from mainaccount order by id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
                                        $sr = 1;
                                        while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($res5))
                                        { ?>
            <tbody>
              <?php foreach($data as $row):?>
              <tr>
              <td><?php  $row5['email']; ?></td>
              <td><?php  $row5['mobile']; ?></td>

              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
          </div></div>  

        </div>
       </body>   
         <script  type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#export-menu li').bind("click", function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('id');
       switch(target) {
    case 'export-to-excel' :
    $('#hidden-type').val(target);
   //alert($('#hidden-type').val());
    $('#export-form').submit();
    $('#hidden-type').val('');
    break
    }
   });
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think the function ExportFile should be called like this:

```
        case "export-to-excel" :
    // Submission from
    $filename = $_POST["ExportType"] . ".xls";       
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    $data = mysql_query("select * from mainaccount order by id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    ExportFile($data);
    //$_POST["ExportType"] = '';
    exit();
```